# Cannot type "b" in gdb prompt

Tags: gdb, putty

When I launch any application under gdb, gdb prompt does not let me type "b". Any other key works fine, "b" is just ignored.

Have anyone seen it? How can I check what's wrong with gdb?

GDB version is 7.6.1; I'm connected to a terminal through ssh (PuTTY).

Comment: Is your keyboard's 'B' key working? Does shift-B do anything? Control-B? Does "b" work when you type it in the putty window, but gdb isn't running?

Comment: @Kenster The keyboard seem fine, "b" and shift-b/ctrl-b work ok in the putty window.